# Object Oriented Programming, Method Call Not Working as Expected, Subclasses

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, extends

I am having trouble with my call to the method makeNoise in the Pets class. I call the makeNoise method through another class, Humans, that has a makePetMakeNoise method:

```
public void makePetMakeNoise()
{
    int randnum = (int)(Math.random() *5);
    pet.makeNoise(randnum);
}
```

---

And I set the pets' canMakeNoise boolean when I create it: Cat a = new Cat("Critter", "Meow", true);

**When I call the Humans' makePetMakeNoise method, I only get a printout like so: Critter *remains silent* instead of: Meow Critter. Why is this, and how do I fix it? Thanks.**

---

```
public class Pets  
{
    String name;
    String noise;
    boolean canMakeNoise;
    public Pets(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise)
{
    name = pname;
    noise = pnoise;
    pcanmakenoise = canMakeNoise;
}

public void makeNoise(int number)
{
    if(canMakeNoise==true)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(noise + " " + name);
        }
    }
    else if(canMakeNoise==false)
    {
        System.out.println(name + " *remains silent*");
    }
}

public void eat()
{
        System.out.println(name + " is eating...");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the assignment for "canMakeNoise" in the constructor is reversed, i.e. assign `canmakenoise = pcanmakenoise`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from

`pcanmakenoise = canMakeNoise;`

to

`canMakeNoise = pcanmakenoise;`

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the constructor parameter pcanmakenoise with the value of canMakeNoise which is currently null.

pcanmakenoise = canMakeNoise;

Answer (score 0):

Default boolean value is false.

canMakeNoise is always false; Hence below condition is always called.

else if(canMakeNoise==false)

Reference ::

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+default+boolean+value&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8